# Should I put all my Javascript together?

Tags: javascript

I'm starting on Javascript and learning best practices, but I haven't found anywhere saying which is better:

1) Separate scripts:

```
<script>
// script A here
</script>

<script>
// script B here
</script>
```

2) Putting scripts together

```
<script>
// script A here
// script B here
</script>
```

Comment: this is a very vague question. You might want to just keep plunging ahead on JavaScript and as you get more experience with it, stuff like this will be more approachable. The general belief is one data request to load all of your JavaScript is superior, but sometimes your JavaScript can become so large that "chunking" it and only loading the parts that are needed can become preferable too.

Answer (score 3):

Neither. Since scripts are usually shared between pages, it's better to keep them separate from your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="urlOfScriptA.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="urlOfScriptB.js"></script>
```

If you cancombine them, you save a request, so it's even better:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="urlOfCombinedScript.js"></script>
```

But for development it can be handy to have separate files. You can use tools to combine and [*minify*](http://www.minifyjavascript.com/) your scripts. That way, not only are they combined into one script (resulting in less requests), but also they are compressed as much as possible, saving bandwidth and loading time.

For now, I wouldn't worry about that yet. Keep the files separate if you think that is easier to work with. And then, later, you can find a tool that can combine and minify them for you. Since this is a slow process, you shouldn't do that on the fly, and it's inconvenient to do it in a development environment, so only combine and minify them when you publish the site.

Answer (score 2):

Organisation.

Do the scripts do stuff directly related to each other?

If yes: Merge.
If no: Keep separate.

(Although ideally they should be in external `.js` files according to the same rules of separation, then merged by a compiler/minifier before being served)

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to put your Javascript on the server as a single file (to prevent files loading in the wrong order).

You can still work in individual files, but use some concatination / minimization software to compile it.

There are lots of different ways to achieve this, but it generally depends on your working environment.